# Why std::vectors is not destroyed from the stack as array?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

When we use arrays and pointers this way:

```
int *g() {
  int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
  return arr;
}

int f() {
  int *value = g();

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    std::cout << value[i] << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
  f();
  return 0;
}
```

It is deleted from the stack after function g returns, so we get a segment error in the function f()

But using `std::vector` this same logic works without any problem:

```
std::vector<int> g() {
  std::vector<int> arr = {1, 2, 3};
  return arr;
}

int f() {
  std::vector<int> value = g();

  for (size_t i = 0; i < value.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << value.at(i) << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
  f();
  return 0;
}
```

I was thinking that this is something related to the fact that we have the std::vector class acting as a container to the array but using a struct as a container delete the array either:

```
struct T {
  int *arr;
};

T g() {
  T t;
  int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
  t.arr = arr;

  return t;
}

int f() {
  T value = g();

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    std::cout << value.arr[i] << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
  f();
  return 0;
}
```

And in this case, g++ allow us to overflow the array pointer memory limits with the index subscription.

Why vectors doesn't share the same problem?

Comment: The built-in arrays are the odd one here. Assume instead of a `std::vector` the variable was just a single `int`. Would you be surprised that you can successfully return it by-value in that case? It is honestly a bit sad when the language is taught in such a way that beginners are surprised that copy-by-value does work in what should be the intuitive way.

Comment: vector is copied, `int arr[]` you create on the stack and that has deleted.

Comment: Replace your C-style arrays with `std::array<int, 3>`.

Comment: "but using a struct as a container" I would not call that struct a container. All it does it house a pointer but does nothing to manage it. On the other hand `std::vector` is much more sophisticated - it has a copy constructor, an assignment operator, etc.

Comment: +1 because this is a well-posed beginner question with enough detail to precisely highlight the point of confusion and generate a good answer. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Your `int f()` function introduces undefined behavior, since you did not return anything.  You're supposed to return an `int`.  Thus any behavior beyond your call of `f()` could be anything.

Answer (score 8):

All the elements in the vector essentially count as part of the vector. And notice you are returning the vector, not a pointer to the vector. But you are returning a pointer to (the start of) the array.

When the function `g` returns, the vector `arr` is destroyed but that's okay because that's not the same one that is returned. A copy of `arr` is returned. (Actually, the compiler is clever enough to reuse the same vector instead of copying it and then deleting one - but you can imagine that it makes a copy)

Then `f` prints values from its own local variable `value` - no problem.

By contrast, in the pointer version, `f` is printing values from the local variable `arr` inside `g`, which has already been destroyed. If `g` would return a pointer to a vector, it would have the same problem.

Comment: *"principle it makes a copy"* That's not entirely accurate. If not for RVO, the `return` statement would result in the return value being move-constructed, not copied. This can have an impact on whether the return statement could throw for more complex functions where RVO is not mandatory...

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition was somewhat right it has something to do with the containment of the array inside a struct, what you misunderstand however is the difference between (**int[]**) and (**int***) and probably you don't understand well where memory resides as well.

To clarify:

In C++ C-style array types (**int[]**), (**char[]**) etc cannot be returned from a function.
Your function does not return (**int[]**) it returns **int*** which is a pointer that points to an an (**int[]**'s zero element in the stack space of some function f() ) and hence the existence of this (**int[]**) stops past the lifetime of the function f(), but a dangling pointer was copied to the caller's site;

Try

```
using int_array = int[4];

int_array f()
{
   int_array arr { 1, 2, 3, 4};
   return arr;  // Does not compile cannot return array
}

int* f2()
{
   int_array arr { 1, 2, 3, 4};
   return arr;  // Compiles because int[4] is implicitly cast to int*
}
```

In the case of vector, it contains a pointer to a dynamically allocated memory block, acquired through some means(new, malloc, custom user defined allocator, etc) hence this memory block is not bound to the lifetime of a function call, but it is managed by the owner of it. When you return the vector to the caller, the memory block behind continues to exist until a (delete, free, custom-delete) is called on it. The vector does this in it's destructor ( **~vector()** ), but before that happening a **vector( const vector& )** constructor call occurs that copies the content of one vector to the other. Most compilers will optimize away this operation, as mentioned by another answer.

In the case where you return the struct, the problem is the same, you are not returning an array (**int[]**) you are returning a pointer. If you were to contain an array inside the struct it would be successfully copied back to caller, because the restriction only applies for arrays and not for user defined types.

Try:

```
struct Foo {
   int arr[4];
};

Foo f() 
{
   Foo obj{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }; // brace initialization of struct
   return obj;
}

int main()
{
   Foo obj = f();
   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      std::cout << i << ' ';  // outputs 1 2 3 4 with no issues
}
```

As you can see no issues with memory here. That's why the std::array<> from  header exists - to wrap C-Style arrays so they can be copied over.

I hope this explains well enough.

Answer (score -1):

In the second method returning `vector<int>`. The `std::vector<int> arr` was copied to another a `temporary vector<int>`, then `std::vector<int> arr` was destroyed.
Finally, the `vector<int> value` was assigned with `temporary vector<int>`, after assigning completed, `temporary vector<int>` was destroyed as well.
That's what i think happening with your example.